# Mysqli - AND OR

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to make my database show my contacts. But other users can give people access to their contacts (this is all stored in tblaccess)

I tried using this sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblcontacts, tblaccess
WHERE (
      tblaccess.user =1
      AND tblaccess.contact = contactID
)
OR tblcontacts.userid =1
```

But it would only return a result if `tblaccess` has a row in.

The conditions are that if tblcontacts.userid <> 1
then check if tblaccess.user = 1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way that I'm understanding your question.  You want all contacts where `userid = 1`, unless there is a record in `tblaccess`.  If there is such a record, then the `user` column must be 1.

The following query implements this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblcontacts c left outer join
     tblaccess a
     on a.contact = c.contactID 
where c.userid = 1 and
      (a.concatId is NULL or
       a.user = 1
      );
```

Comment: Thanks, i modified your sample to get it working :) as when i first wrote the question i messed the conditionals up :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to have too many conditionals - this is what `JOIN`s are for. I believe that a `RIGHT JOIN` is what you're looking for. This is untested, but should return a NULL value on the right side if `tablecontacts` returns a userid 1 but `tablecontacts` does not have a userid.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblcontacts
RIGHT JOIN tblaccess ON tblaccess.user=tblcontacts.userid
WHERE tablecontacts.userid=1
```

**UPDATE**

Sounds like you are looking for two separate pieces of data from two separate tables. I know they are both IDs, but there is no foreign key to connect to in either table. In fact, the data in one table may well not be in another table. For this reason you will probably want to run a `UNION` query. That will allow you to pull anybody in either table that holds these values.

```
SELECT * FROM tblaccess WHERE user=1 AND contact = contactID
UNION
SELECT * FROM tblcontact WHERE userid=1
```

Alternatively, you could create a prepared statement or put the logic into your programming language.

A quick note - I would recommend explicitly calling your columns. Most people far more experienced than I would be hammering that home so figured I'd politely suggest it.

Comment: Thanks, but I messed my question up so I edited it, my conditions should be that if the tblcontacts.userid isn't equal to 1 then check the access table to find the contacts that has user equal to one.

Comment: Thanks, although it wasnt what i was after, after look at Gordon's answer and modifying it slightly i managed to get it to work but thanks for the help :)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tblcontacts
WHERE tblcontacts.userid = 1
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM tblaccess
            WHERE tblaccess.user = 1)
```

Comment: Avoid subqueries in such scenarios, MySQL is not optimized to translate these queries into a join in the execution plan. You should instead use a join, thats what they are for and it's the perfect example!